I've created child items (tasks) in a gitlab issue. This issue is now split in two. How to move some children of the first issue to the second one?
To help my product owner, I've detailed my backlog issue "Story" into tasks that appears in its Child Items list.
Story
description
Child items

(X) First Task
( ) Second task
( ) Third task
( ) Fourth task

He says: "Too much work to do, here. Let's split this story in two parts, one being done later"
Story to do later
description
Child items

( ) Third task
( ) Fourth task

I've yet found no way to move a child item/task that have been created in a given story to another one.
Change it's ancestor or parent with gitlab.
Is there a way to do so?


Change it's ancestor or parent with gitlab.
Is there a way to do so?

Yes, you are correct. You have to remove the tasks from the existing issue and add them to the new issue.
